# How can I insert double quotes (") between two columns using sed/awk/perl

Tags: perl, sed, awk

I have a file with contents:

```
Version:2.0
```

I need an output in the following format:

```
"Version":"2.0"
```

How should I insert double quotes in these columns ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple one-liner:

```
perl -plwe 's/([^:]+)/"$1"/g'
```

Take anything that is not a colon and put quotes around it. Because of the `-l` option we avoid this including the newline at the end.

Comment: this actually prints `:` only from all the columns. Doesn't put `Version:2.0` in double quotes.

Comment: @AshutoshNarayan I don't know what to tell you about that except: No, it doesn't only print a colon from all columns, and yes it does put that in double quotes. The only way for the regex to remove anything is if it matches, and if it matches, it also captures and replaces. If it doesn't work for you, it is because you changed it somehow, or your shell is despite everything interpolating `$1` - but even so, the quotes would still be inserted. So, no, what you say happened cannot happen with this code.

Comment: yes it does inserts the double quotes. I guess I would have missed something. Acceptable.

Comment: @TLP: Doesn't it feel great to have offered an "acceptable" solution!

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -r 's/(^|$)/"/g;s/:/":"/' file

kent$  echo "Version:2.0"|sed -r 's/(^|$)/"/g;s/:/":"/'  
"Version":"2.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F":" -v OFS=":" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){$i="\""$i"\"";}print}'
```

tested:

```
> echo "Version:2.0" | awk -F":" -v OFS=":" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){$i="\""$i"\"";}print}'
"Version":"2.0"
```

or

```
perl -F -lane 'for(@F){$_="\"".$_."\"";}print join ":",@F'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 perl -lpe'$_ = join ":",map qq{"$_"},split /:/' myfile
```

Comment: @Borodin.I like your solution.

Comment: @sarathi: Thanks. Not as brief as some others (my favourite is TLP's) but IMO it describes what it does.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another `sed` alternative:

```
echo Version:2.0 | sed 's/[^:]*/"&"/g'
```

Output:

```
"Version":"2.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

In perl, you can do it like this:

```
perl -pe "s/([^:]+):(.+)/\"\1\":\"\2\"/" YourTextFile.txt
```

**Edit 1:** In Linux, using `$1` and `$2` instead of `\1` and `\2` causes the strings that should be quoted to be empty - the output is then '"":""'. I think this due to the dollar `$` being a special character in some *nix shells. Escaping the dollars works as well:

```
perl -pe "s/([^:]+):(.+)/\"\$1\":\"\$2\"/" YourTextFile.txt
```

**Edit 2:** As @TLP suggested, using single quotes is the way to go for *nix, as it avoids shell interpolation and also allows to drop all of the escapes.

```
perl -pe 's/([^:]+):(.+)/"$1":"$2"/' YourTextFile.txt
```

Comment: It throws output as `"":""` and not `"Version":"2.0"`

Comment: That's weird! On Windows w/Perl 5.16 it works, but on Linux w/Perl 5.10 it behaves as you describe. Anyway, a fix is to use a backslash for instead of dollar for the back-references - Editing answer...

Comment: Use single quotes in linux to avoid shell interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

I think this `awk` snippet might help:

```shell
gawk -F: '{gsub("\"", "\"\""); \
  for(i=1;i<NF;i++) printf("\"%s\":",$i); \
  printf("\"%s\"\n",$NF); }' testfile
```

It does extra job and doubles existsing quotes.

And to create test file I've used the following code:

```
cat << EODATA > testfile
Version:2.0
Some:field:with:double(")quotes
EODATA
```